# Boxplots with R of each column (no grouped data)

Tags: r, graph

My data is a simple dataframe, where each column represents the values of a group:

```
df <- data.frame(c(6:13), c(1:8))
colnames(df) <- c("Group1","Group2")
```

Now i would like to plot a boxplot of every group in one graph.
I didn't get this to work by using the standard boxplot function, since the data is not grouped but separated already). I was fiddling with boxplot.matrix but no success neither:

```
boxplot.matrix(df, use.cols = T, col=1:2)
```

I am too complicated here? it should be a pretty simple task!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will automatically do if for you.  Just do:

```
boxplot(df)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh no, thought way too complicated! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, @Madamadam. Good luck.